# Is there any way of programmatically setting up a Monthly Cost Allocation Report in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Basically, is there any way of doing [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html#allocation-report) [1] via API or AWS CLI?

I need to automate this for new accounts being set-up, and would like to avoid having to log in to each one of them to enable it.

Regards.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html#allocation-report

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`PutReportDefinition`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/operations.html) in the Billing and Cost Management API?  If `DescribeReportDefinitions` will fetch an existing one, then that should be something you can reuse.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, that is it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As *Michael - sqlbot* pointed out, the programmatic way of doing this is via [AWS Billing and Cost Management API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/operations.html).

In fact, per comment in AWS documentation, detailed billing and month allocation reports are in the path of deprecation.